# How fast is the position of the airplane moving?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had this question on a calculus final, and I'm wondering if I got the right answer. (I'm remembering it from memory, so if something seems strange, it's me.)

An airplane is flying at an altitude of 9 units (don't remember which). It flew over area A at 270 miles per hour. When the plane is 10 units away from A, how fast is the position of the airplane changing in relation to area A?

**Edit**: The question was how fast the distance is changing, and the plane is flying at a constant altitude. The answer I got was 240.something, I think.

Here is an image of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtkG0.jpg

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: How is the position measured relative to area A? If the plane is still over area A, since the distance is measured perpendicular to the ground, the position is moving at the plane's speed.

Comment: @martycohen, I believe they mean area A to be a point on the ground, and overall distance includes altitude, so that the distance from the plane to A when the plane is directly above A is 9, after which it is a related rates problem using a triangle.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. If so, I think they should have said "point A".

Answer (score 1):

Since it was a calculus final, you probably shouldn't use the simple non-calculus solution;  but, just in case...

At the moment of interest, the plane is at altitude 9 units, and is 10 units ***in a direct line*** from Point A.  So its horizontal distance from Point A is $\sqrt{19}$ units, and the angle of elevation, $\theta$, is given by:$$\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{19}}{10}$$
Looking at the plane, its horizontal velocity of $270$ can be split into $2$ perpendicular components.  The component along the line of sight from Point A to the plane is elevated by the same angle $\theta$, and is given by $270\times \cos{\theta}$.